# Как из pythona с помощью asyncpg сделать sql запрос с переменным количеством входных данных?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Как из Python с помощью `asyncpg` сделать SQL-запрос с переменным количеством входных данных (количество входных данных в кортеже определяется в рантайме)? К примеру, у меня есть строка запроса

```
SELECT word, translation FROM dictionary WHERE id IN($1, $2)
```

как вместо `$1, $2` сделать так, чтобы запрос определял количество переменных, исходя из количества элементов кортежа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По мне, как один из допустимых вариантов - использовать массивы в postgresql.

```
conn = await asyncpg.connect(connection_url)
rows = await conn.fetch("SELECT word, translation FROM dictionary WHERE id = ANY($1::int[]);", [1,2])
```

Вместо `$1::int[]` будет подставлен `ARRAY([1, 2])`.

Как здесь https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/496.

А `WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY([1, 2]))` сработает как использование оператора `IN`.

Как описано здесь http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/7468.

Поэтому в качестве ответа вернется из базы две записи с id равными 1 и 2.